# Prevent MySQL to update more then one row

Tags: mysql

I faced the situation that somehow a user succeeded in setting a column to a certain value in a table for all rows.

I don't fully understand the situation how this could happen. Luckily it seems not to have been a hacker using some SQL injection or whatever but an unfortunate user behavior (which I can not reproduce).

Anyway: In real life never ever should it be needed that more than one row is updated at once.

So my question: is there a possibility (trigger?) to avoid a multi row update?

Something like if row_count() > 1 then error - but **before** the update is actually executed?

Or can it be rollback'ed?

Comment: Can you share the original query.. sometimes a where statement is missing

Comment: No, you can't limit updates except by using the proper WHERE clause. If all rows were updated, then a) your user was allowed to run a SQL statement; and b) that user ran a SQL statement without a WHERE clause. The way to prevent this is to not allow your users to run SQL statements they enter themselves, but to use stored procedures they can call with parameters instead. That stored procedure can restrict it to rows that match a set condition.

Comment: update table set value = 'x' where key = '123' - it's not more complicated than that. However: there are e.g. empty keys; and if the user enters an empty key, that would update ALL rows with empty keys. Of course I checked that the key cannot be empty but somehow it happened anyway.